# VPN authentication in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, vpn

I have a VPN in my office. One machine has windows server 2003 installed. I am coding an app in C# to upload files from a machine connected to the server machine on a shared folder.

The file transfer code has been written, but it throw Access denied exception when I run it.

However when I open the shared folder using windows explorer and key in my username and password, then it works like a charm.

I need to know why it's throwing this exception and what code should I write to automatically authenticate myself from the code without going to windows explorer and entering credentials there.

Update --

.net version is 2.0, I can upgrade if its necessary but I dont think its the issue.
Iam running the application on the local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using impersonation.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q306158

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cpimpersonation1.aspx